# EclassImpl setEPackage()

Tags: java, emf

I need to work with some emf code without having any clue how it works. The code uses EcoreUtil.copy(...) to clone the classes. I added a EClass to the class i created like this:

```
    EClassImpl c = (EClassImpl)EcoreFactory.eINSTANCE.createEClass();
    System.out.println(c.getEPackage().getEFactoryInstance());
```

And also overrode eStaticClass() like this:

```
    @Override
    protected EClass eStaticClass() {       
        EClassImpl c = (EClassImpl)EcoreFactory.eINSTANCE.createEClass();
        return c;
    }
```

Now i have the problem, that the copy routine tries to use:

```
    eClass.getEPackage().getEFactoryInstance().create(eClass);
```

Which returns a nullpointer exception, since getEPackage() returns null. Unfortunatly there seems to be no setter for the EPackage, so how do i set it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve it myself, here is my solution in case anybody else ever comes across this:

```
    EPackageImpl epi = (EPackageImpl)EcoreFactory.eINSTANCE.createEPackage();
    c.eBasicSetContainer(epi, EcorePackage.ECLASSIFIER__EPACKAGE, null);
```

Answer (score 2):

Had the same problem. See in http://emfjson.org/docs/ how they use the API as an example.

```
samplePackage
.getEClassifiers()
.add(userClass);
```

This will add the class to the package and vice versa.

Comment: Thank you, if I ever come across it again I'll give your solution a shot, it seems cleaner